# Adding JPanels to a JPanel at Run Time

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jpanel

I wrote a java code that draws a molecule on a JPanel

I drag and drop this JPanel on to another JPanel using Netbeans IDE and call setMolecule(mol)

This works great.

However instead of drag and drop if I do

```
MolViewer mv = new MolViewer();
mv.setLayout(BorderLayout());
mv.setMolecule(mol);
SomeJpanel.setLayout(BorderLayout());
SomeJPanel.add(mv)
SomeJPanel.revalidate();
SomeJPanel.repaint();
```

it does not work ??

What am I doing Wrong??

Comment: did you try a pack() on the SomeJPanel.